# Subdirect product of simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a subdirect product of simple groups $G_i$ for $i\in I$. I want to show that if $1\neq x\in G$, then there exists a maximal normal subgroup $N$ such that $x\notin N$.

First of all, I know that if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then we have $\pi_i(N)=0$ or $G_i$ for every projection $\pi_i$.

I can't show that there exists a maximal normal subgroup $N$ such that $x\notin N$.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: "subdirect" product?Is this restricted direct product (what others know simply as "direct product" or restricted cartesian product), or something else?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdirect_product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is contained in every maximal normal subgroup. Then every projection of $x$ on $G_i$ is the identity, since the kernel of the projection onto $G_i$ is a maximal normal subgroup ($G_i$ is simple). However, by definition of subdirect product, the map from $G$ into $\prod G_i$ is injective, a contradiction.

Comment: Dear Jack. By definition of subdirect product, the  projection map from G into $G_i$ is a surjective map. Why does it implies that the map from G into $\Pi G_i$ is injective

Comment: Well the definition I learned was that $G \leq \prod G_i$ such that each projection is surjective. The wikipedia article defines it using an official inclusion map, but that inclusion map should be injective.

Comment: If you take $G \leq \prod G_i$ as your definition, then “every projection of $x$” can be replaced by “every entry of $x$”, and the identity of $G$ is exactly that sequence in which every entry is the identity.